# distinct select not working properly 

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct

Okay, i'm trying to copy unique records in one table across to another, then write them back in an effort to weed out *exact* duplicates. Below are the queries I am using to do that.

```
// create new "temp" table
$Database->Query = "
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TempQuickIcon` (
  `ListingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `QuickIconID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
";
$Database->RunQuery();

// insert distinctive values but only for this listing id
$Database->Query = "INSERT INTO TempQuickIcon(`ListingID`,`QuickIconID`) SELECT DISTINCT `ListingID`,`QuickIconID` FROM `_ListingQuickIcon` WHERE `ListingID` = '{$GetNewListingID}'";
$Database->RunQuery();

// delete this listings records from the original table
$Database->NewTransaction();
$Database->Table = "_ListingQuickIcon";
$Database->Conditions = "`ListingID` = '{$GetNewListingID}'";
$Database->DeleteRecord();

// insert records from "temp" table
$Database->Query = "INSERT INTO _ListingQuickIcon(`ListingID`,`QuickIconID`) SELECT DISTINCT `ListingID`,`QuickIconID` FROM `TempQuickIcon`";
$Database->RunQuery();

$Database->Query = "TRUNCATE TABLE `TempQuickIcon`";
$Database->RunQuery();
```

Okay, so obviously i have a database wrapper but I have ensured that there are no functional problems therein by testing them one-by-one. I have also tested each query one-by-one and the procedure works.

However, when I try run the entire sequence of queries together, in otherwords to execute the script ... it processes without errors but doesn't actually seem to follow the DISTINCT and copies two (or more ... if there are multiple duplicates) records into TempQuickIcon.

But if I run each part of the script individually, the DISTINCT is followed and only the unique records get copied.

I'm aware that it must be something stupid and that i'm making a mistake somewhere. But I cannot see it.

Any thoughts? I'll obviously provide what I can.

Comment: First thought: Would you have to commit the transaction started with NewTransaction()? This migth be a difference, because when you run it "step by step", your session might be closed between the single steps while it stays open running it as a whole.

Comment: Why not just run `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempQuickIcon LIKE _ListingQuickIcon;`, add some unique key and then `REPLACE INTO TempQuickIcon SELECT * FROM _ListingQuickIcon; DROP TABLE _ListingQuickIcon; RENAME TempQuickIcon TO _ListingQuickIcon;`?

Comment: technically, that NewTransation() function doesn't have to be there, as it's a wrapper function designed for building up fields for INSERT or UPDATE queries. Ultimately, all that DeleteRecord() does is "DELETE FROM `_ListingQuickIcon` WHERE `ListingID` = '{$GetNewListingID'"

Comment: rik: the table is going to get particularly large, i'm not sure if cloning the table all the time is going to be as efficient as an indexed select? it's worth investigating though.

Comment: Why are you putting quotes around {$GetNewListingID} in your SELECT (and DELETE)? If ListingID's an integer, you don't need them. Doubt it's related to the problem, but something odd could be going on because of it, I suppose, depending on the rest of the code...

Comment: Matt, force of habit really. Perhaps a bad practice, but it doesn't affect the problem in any way, as I've just removed and tested. I'm perplexed.

Comment: Okay, somehow it appears to be linked with my sending of an INSERT .... SELECT from my wrapper to mysqli itself. Each QUERY runs fine by itself, and works fine if i use direct mysqli->xxx commands, but when I run the same query from my wrapper, it ignores the DISTINCT. So further investigation is needed.

Comment: If DISTINCT is not working you might want to try a GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was based on me, as a part of my database wrapper, executing a function to fetch the results of the query when running 'RunQuery()' ... which was designed for things like TRUNCATE or CREATE TABLE, etc etc. However, I suspect that when it tried to execute the query and fetch results, it executed twice because it was trying to get a result set. I can't quite vocalise it, but the long story short is that I was trying to fetch a record set when there wasn't one to fetch, but it affected the write process.

Doesn't help that this is the first time i've needed to do an INSERT .... SELECT with the wrapper. Lesson learnt :)

Comment: I knew it was something stoopid :P

Answer (score 0):

Can any of the fields in your `SELECT DISTINCT ...` be `NULL`?  Because `NULL!=NULL`, `DISTINCT` doesn't consider row X where fieldA IS NULL and  rowY where fieldA IS NULL to be the same.

Comment: a keen idea, but no ... both fields across both tables are NOT NULL. :\